# Adding JavaScript in Datalist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, escaping, datalist

That's my code but that says not well formed.

How can I correct  that?

```
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' onClick="<%#"javascript:popUp(\'gallery_detail.aspx?cat_id=\""+ Eval("ID") +"\"\')"%>"></asp:HyperLink>
    <br />
    <br />
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved....

```
<ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' onClick='<%#"javascript:popUp(gallery_detail.aspx?cat_id=\""+Eval("ID")+"\")"%>'></asp:HyperLink>
            <br />
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
```

When you write code if write add an ASP.net code in tags- Put ' char not "
That's All...